# Whats the name of that remote control software for Canon digital cameras and where can I get it?

Tags: camera

A year ago I stumbled upon a software that was able to control my Canon PowerShot G5 with USB. I was able to see a preview and take snapshots, do some settings, etc. Can't find that anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gPhoto](http://gphoto.sourceforge.net/doc/remote/) (Linux) or [PSRemote](http://www.breezesys.com/PSRemote/) (Windows), perhaps?

Comment: It was an app directly from Canon. 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check out CHDK - it's a non-permanent firmware override that allows remote control, as well as fine grained adjustments to many settings, on most Canon cameras.